# consuming a service layer with django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I've been using tastypie for a few days and I must say it is amazing for CRUD operations. I've implemented validators to do some basic business validations but now I need to do something extra...

After creating a model I must do some logging, send an email and other extra stuff. So, from my perspective I'd like to have a service layer and being able to call a method after the model is persisted.

This should not go in the dehydrate method from my perspective... So, how can I add business processing in tastypie?

Besides that, I have another business unit where I must provide an API just for exposing an already created service that is no CRUD. It returns system data, but no Model is associated. Is tastypie suitable for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use tastypie for any resource.

Here is the documentation of tastypie with non-orm resources:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/non_orm_data_sources.html

And another example:

https://github.com/fatiherikli/tastypie-mongodb-resource/blob/master/tastypie_mongodb/resources.py